# In a .NET Core 2 WebAPI app, what is the scope and lifetime of a dbcontext

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2 WebAPI application. In Startup class' ConfigureServices I add a DbContext with services.AddDbContext<> and a repository with services.AddScoped<,>...

**When is the dbcontext created and how long does it last?**

I my WPF desktop days I created my dbcontext within a Using statement, so, I always knew the scope. But now the lifetime of the dbcontext is a little less obvious to me in the Core 2 WebAPI. And, multiple users can hit the API at the same time, do each of them get their own dbcontext?

Comment: Each individual HTTP request gets its own instance, created and disposed by the DI container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the context is added "scoped" in ASP.NET Core parlance, which means really *request*-scoped for the most part. Your main application runs just once (everything in `Startup`, etc.). For each request, a unique request pipeline is created, which involves newing up things like controllers, which will then be disposed at the end of the request. With a request-scoped context, your context, too, will be newed up the first time it needs to be injected in the request pipeline, and all future uses of the at context, within the same request pipeline, will use the same context. At the end of the request, it will be disposed.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks